# JPanel still has buttons after removeall()

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a project which is using a `JPanel` populated with dynamically generated buttons, read from a list which is populated from a DB.
I have a next and a previous button to shuffle through the pages.
Everything works fine on the first two pages, but on the third, when the remaining size of the list is less than 32(max buttons to fit perfectly on the page), and only 5 buttons remain to be "generated", the old buttons from the previous page show up, even though I call `jPanel.removeAll()`, and I tried to add `jPanel.revalidate()` also.

Note, the lists content does not change.

Here is the code:

```
private void loadCat(int catnr) { //loads second,third,etc. category page
    jMainPanel.removeAll();
    jMainPanel.revalidate();

    for (int i = catnr; i < engine.LoadItems.catlist.size(); i++) {
        if (i == catnr + 32) // more than 32 buttons do not fit per page
            break;
        final JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        btn.setText(engine.LoadItems.catlist.get(i));
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                //some code here (...)
            }
       });
       jMainPanel.add(btn);
       jMainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(436, 480));
       jMainPanel.revalidate();  
    }
}
```

Question: How do I get the panel to display only the remaining items on page 3(or on any page in the future)? What am I doing wrong?

Screenshots:

[image: http://oi59.tinypic.com/2dqisug.jpg]

[image: http://oi60.tinypic.com/ifoqiu.jpg]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding add/remove components call

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

revalidate calls layout manager to recalculate all the components' sizes and repaint repaints newly sized components.